# Python's os.path libraries equivalent in Groovy

Tags: python, groovy, path

Is there an equivalent module for Groovy as Python's os.path?

Comment: You mean like [Java's `File` object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the `os.path` functionality is found in the methods on the [`java.io.File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class.  In addition, if you're using Java 1.7, there are some additional methods in [`java.nio.file.Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html).

Also note that groovy transparently adds some new addtional functionality on top of Java.  These additional methods are documented here: http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html

Answer (score 2):

The standard `java.io.File` Java class can do a lot of the same things, and Groovy adds its own extensions (see http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk).